# TFS 2012/2013 Selective Branching

Tags: tfs, branch

I'm wondering if there is a way to selectively branch files and folders in TFS. We currently branch the trunk but it is a bit cumbersome.

Lets say I have the following structure:

```
 --trunk
   --base code
   --internal code that relies on base code
   --client code that relies on base code
```

I would like to branch base and internal and base and client.

if this is not possible what would be a good folder structure to facilitate our needs?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than including base (the dependency) in the source for your internal/client, a typical approach is to have base in it's own branch.  Then have internal and client take a binary dependency rather than a source dependency on base.

This is realized by having a lib folder in each internal and client, that contains a copy of the specific version of base on which they have a dependency.  This allows you to evolve base and the applications that depend on it independently, and it allows the internal/client developers to make an explicit decision about which version of base to depend on.

Comment: Yes thats an approach I have used in the past we tended to create nuget packages for the dependencies, the only issue is that we embed shared views in the base project and tend to change that a lot during a development. This is easy if you have the project in your solution but becomes cumbersome if you have to have two projects open? it would also mean feature A would have two seperate branches during development, one for base feature A and one for internal feature A. which is a bit of an issue.